# Setting UIBarButtonItem appearance is only working after a delay

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am setting all of my appearance() overrides in `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)`

Most of them are working correctly, however the UIBarButtonItem font changes only seem to be working after a delay. Here is how I am setting them:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
   [.font: UIFont.regularFont(size: 18)!],
   for: .normal)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
   [.font: UIFont.regularFont(size: 18)!],
   for: .selected)
```

When I first launch the app, I see the following where the BarButtonItem is using the system font rather than my custom font. However, the title navigation bar font is correct:
[image]
When I navigate to another tab and back, I see the correct font:
[image]

I also attempted to move the appearance overrides into AppDelegate, but that had no impact

Comment: What you're doing is illegal. Do not set the appearance proxy's title text attributes directly. Use the UIBarButtonItemAppearance class. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitemstateappearance

Comment: When I follow those instructions and comment my old code out, it never modifies the font.
UIBarButtonItemAppearance().normal.titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.regularFont(size: 18)!] as well as all the other itemStates does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out thanks to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar)

```
let navAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
let bbItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
bbItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.regularFont(size: 18)!]
navAppearance.buttonAppearance = bbItemAppearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navAppearance
```

Comment: Just as I said.